# overwrite contents of a file: alternative to `>`?

Tags: bash

I often find myself stringing together a series of shell commands, ultimately with the goal to replace the contents of a file. However, when using `>` it opens the original file for writing, so you lose all the contents.

For lack of a better term, is there a "lazy evaluation" version of `>` that will wait until all the previous commands have been executed before before opening the file for writing?

Currently I'm using:

```
somecommand file.txt | ... | ... > tmp.txt && rm file.txt && mv tmp.txt file.txt
```

Which is quite ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sponge` will help here:

(Quoting from the manpage)

> NAME
>          sponge - soak up standard input and write to a file
>
> SYNOPSIS
>          sed '...' file | grep '...' | sponge file
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          sponge  reads  standard  input and writes it out to the specified file.
>          Unlike a shell redirect, sponge soaks up all its input  before  opening
>          the  output file. This allows constructing pipelines that read from and
>          write to the same file.
>
> ```
>   It also creates the output file atomically by renaming a temp file into
>    place,  and  preserves the permissions of the output file if it already
>    exists.  If the output file is a special file or symlink, the data will
>    be written to it.
>
>   If no output file is specified, sponge outputs to stdout.
> ```

See also: [Can I read and write to the same file in Linux without overwriting it? on unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/36268/13439)