# How to set a property of a json file and replace in one command using jq

Tags: bash, batch-file, jq

[How do I update a single value in a json document using jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31034746/how-do-i-update-a-single-value-in-a-json-document-using-jq) Doesn't have the answer for this question.

1. Read json file.
2. Update the value.
3. Replace the file.

Expecting **one inline command** using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Assume I have following json file.

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "value": "one",
  ... 
}
```

I want to update the value field to "two". So resulting json file should look like

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "value": "two",
  ... 
}
```

What is the simplest bash command and windows bat command for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a demonstration of a solution that uses [sponge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21867969/overwrite-contents-of-a-file-alternative-to/21868000#21868000)

```
bash-3.2$ cat data.json
{
  "name": "app",
  "value": "one"
}

bash-3.2$ jq -M '.value="two"' < data.json | sponge data.json 

bash-3.2$ cat data.json 
{
  "name": "app",
  "value": "two"
}
```

Comment: sponge: command not found. overwriting file is file.

Comment: sponge can be found in [moreutils](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/). There is a windows version [here](https://github.com/zetamatta/sponge)

Comment: can you give me the command with replacing the file using ">"

Comment: There are some examples in [these discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+sponge+moreutils), e.g. [Bash: Is it ok to use same input file as output of a piped command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055005/bash-is-it-ok-to-use-same-input-file-as-output-of-a-piped-command/3055080#3055080) but I would recommend using sponge.

Comment: this only works for replacing values of properties in the first level of nesting